# Base64_encode for URLS

Tags: php, base64

Is there a base64_encode function that is URL safe in PHP?

It also needs to be decodable obviously.

Answer (score 3):

```
urlencode(base64_encode($var));
```

Comment: This can strip off the '=' signs that are necessary for base64_decode.

Answer (score 1):

No. There isn't one built-in.

You can simply do this,

```
$encoded = strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/=', '-_.');
$data = base64_decode(strtr($encoded, '-_.', '+/='));
```